# Reading Config File Contents

Tags: java, config

I am trying to read a "DB_Config_File.properties" file but for some reason the following error is occurring:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
```

My class that is handling the reading of the config file looks like the following:

public class database {

```
public static Connection conn;
public static void dbConnection() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        driver = props.getProperty("driver");
        String url = props.getProperty("url");
        String username = props.getProperty("username"); 
        String password = props.getProperty("password");
        String configFile = "F:/Project/Java Project/src/mainScreen/DB_Config_File.properties";

        InputStream ins = new FileInputStream(configFile); 
        props.load(ins);
        Class.forName(driver);


        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
```

}

Judging by the error I am guessing there is something wrong in the "Class.forName(driver)" part.

Can you please help me out here?

Thanks

Comment: Your code seems to ordered illogically.

Comment: Could you add more detailed stacktrace ? In your code there is `java.lang.NullPointerException` but we can't infer which point is rising this exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the properties file from the input stream after you are reading values from it. The variable 'driver' is null as the properties are empty and is causing the NPE.

Comment: Bingo!  I'm new at this so mind my silly mistakes :).

Comment: While we're at it.... how can I read the mentioned properties file without pasting the whole path (F:/Project/Java Project/src/mainScreen/DB_Config_File.properties).  What I mean, is there a way that I can read the file from class hierarchy by simply pasting the properties file?

Comment: You can use load it from the  [classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String) or pass a path in via the command line. There are also libraries such as [Archaius](https://github.com/Netflix/archaius) that can do some of the magic for you.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt help.